# Jenkins : Invalid gitTool selection Git

Tags: ios, windows, build, jenkins

i've setup my own jenkins buildserver today on my windows PC to build commits to my bitbucket.org-repository automatically.

Sadly i'm deep in trouble with the conenction between jenkins and git.

This is my Jenkis-Git configuration:
[image]

This is the Jobconfiguration:
[image]

If i now run "Build now" i'm getting the following output in console:
[image]

I hope somebody here is abled to help me with this problem. The Job is building... and building... and building... no result.

Kind regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get these Git-related warnings as well, but Jenkins is working just fine for me. I believe that they can be ignored. There is [an open issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19246) about this.

Answer (score 1):

1. confirm you do indeed have Git installed on your system. try again.
2. If still having issue, you may need to also add the path of the Git executable to your Node configuration. By going to your Node configuration page, 'Node Properties' section, 'Tools Locations' setting. There you will find an option to explicitly add the path to Git.